# Create array with tags on jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, tags

I want to get all the "p" from body and create one array, then use this array to print the text content of every one "p", how can I archive it? Very novice question but i'm stuck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is plenty method to do it, wheater using pure JavaScript or jQuery:

**JavaScript:**

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p'); // Get all paragraphs (it's fastest way by using getElementsByTagName)
var pTexts = []; // Define an array which will contain text from paragraphs


// Loop through paragraphs array

for (var i = 0, l = p.length; i < l; i++) {
    pTexts.push(p[i].textContent); // add text to the array
}
```

**Loop jQuery way:**

```
$.each(p, function(i, el) {
    pTexts.push(el.textContent);

    // or using jQuery text(), pretty much the same as above
    // pTexts.push( $(el).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `.map()` in jquery

```
var result = $("body").find("p").map(function() {
   return $(this).text();
}).get();

 console.log(result);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gxtszrxy/)